# Drop element to list which are in the same list. vue-smooth-dnd

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I using vue-smooth-dnd component.

How i can drop Drop element to list which are in the same list?

In official documentation i found only this https://kutlugsahin.github.io/vue-smooth-dnd/#/nested.

But i need something like this.

[image: Trying to dnd between list and elements in the same list]

Answer (score 0):

Use group-name in container, like:

```
<Container
  group-name="parent"
  ...
>
...
</Container>
```